# TypeError: connectDB is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Переписываю задачку из видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z57566JBaZQ 10 минута

При запуске `npm run dev` выдает ошибку.

> TypeError: connectDB is not a function
>       at Object. (/home/andrey/Рабочий стол/urlCutter/index.js:7:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Сам код выглядит так:

index.js

```
 const express = require('express');
    const connectDB = require('./config/db');   
    const app = express();    
    //connect to DB
    connectDB();    
    app.use(express.json({extented: false})); 
    const PORT = 5000;
    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
        console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

config/db.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');
const connectDB = async () => {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log("MongoDB connected");
    }catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};
```

config/default.json

```
{
  "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0-j7nbw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

package.json

```
  {
      "name": "urlCutter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node index",
        "dev": "nodemon index"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "config": "^3.2.4",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.7.7",
        "shortid": "^2.2.15",
        "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
      }
    }
```

Почему то не срабатывает `const connectDB = require('./config/db');` в файле index.js. Когда переношу весь код из файла db.js в файл index.js  все отрабатывает как надо. 
Подскажите пожалуйста чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В файле db.js допишите  module.exports = connectDB

Comment: Спасибо! 
Сделал, все работает!